# Can an Arduino (Leonardo) be recognized via Bluetooth as a mouse/keyboard?

Tags: bluetooth, atmega32u4, arduino-uno-wifi

I'm new to wireless communication on Arduinos and doing research for a project. I'm looking at the [Arduino Leonardo](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-leonardo-with-headers) (which is like the Uno) which via its micro USB port can be automatically recognized as a mouse/keyboard. But also looking at a regular Uno wiFi Rev2.

I want to achieve the same result, but wirelessly via Bluetooth. Because I need to connect it to a device that only recognizes Bluetooth mice/keyboards and nothing else. If I buy something like the [HC-05](https://www.intorobotics.com/pick-right-bluetooth-module-diy-arduino-project/) how would the chip report itself?

How is the Bluetooth stack handled with regards to identification and authentication? Does it somehow copy the USB mouse/keyboard setup?

PS: Can anyone tell me if the Wifi Arduinos (Uno WiFi rev2) also have Bluetooth embedded?

Comment: warning, there is nothing regular on Uno WiFi Rev 2. It is completely different from Uno

Comment: I meant to say Leonardo is not regular because it has a built in usb keyboard thingy on chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I buy something like the HC-05 how would the chip report itself?

As an SPP. I.e., a serial port.

> How is the bluetooth stack handled with regards to identification and authentication?

By the firmware on the HC-05

> Does it somehow copy the usb mouse/keyboard setup?

No.

You need a USB device that can emulate a keyboard. That's not the HC-05. The host microcontroller has absolutely nothing to do with what capabilities the bluetooth interface has.

Comment: Ok so the HC-05 can't spoof itself to report itself as a specific thing (keyboard). And even if it did it would not have anything to do with the on-chip built in usb thingy the leonardo has. Cool. So I'll probably try to find a usb-to-bluetooth keyboard adapter, or research a more advanced way to spoof a keyboard via bluetooth with a regular arduino like the uno wifi rev 2.